# Open Pinta or other simple photo editor after ctrl+shift+printscr

Tags: gnome, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

What I usually do with screenshots:

List item

1. Ctrl + Shift + PrintScr
2. Paste into chat or wherever

What I like to do is add a step or two between that. As in:

1. Take screenshot
2. Simple edit (add text, crop, draw arrows or circles)
3. Paste into wherever

I know I can do this by saving the file with `Shift + PrintScr` but I want the quick flow that Windows had with it's snipping tool.

I've looked into **Shutter** but it doesn't look like it's in active development anymore and I've seen mentions of annoying bugs.

Google just keeps suggesting Gnome screenshot.

Comment: I have the Mate desktop. Shutter  works perfectly and has a simple editor built in.

Comment: I can vouch for Shutter too as @ravery did. Works pretty fine for me. But if you're using Ubuntu 17.10, keep in mind that it won't work in a Wayland session. You'll have to switch to an Xorg session.